# Opening the 'Files' application (Pantheon Files) displays the screen at the state of which it was closed. Is there a way to change this?

Tags: pantheon-files, slingshot

Upon opening 'Files' from the slingshot application manager, you are greeted with the directory of which 'Files' was at when it was last closed. For example, if I were to open 'Files' and go to 'Documents' and then close this window, when I open 'Files' again, it'll open into the 'Documents' directory by default. Is there any way to change this so that it opens instead to the 'Home' directory (pictured) regardless of it's last closed state, instead of opening into one of the sub-folders such as 'Pictures' 'Documents' etc?

Thanks,
Robbie

[image: Home Directory]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In dconf editor open

```
org -> pantheon -> files -> preferences
```

and uncheck the box "restore tabs".

This will open your home directory every time you open pantheon files.